# Python fmin_l_bfgs_b keeps evaluating function over and over

Tags: python, optimization, scipy

I'm attempting to use the L-BFGS-B method in python to optimize a function and in some cases it works fine and finds the minimum pretty quickly, but in some cases it is doing something I don't entirely understand.

In particular, it will just keep evaluating my function over and over and over again during one iteration. I verified that this is happening by simply adding a "print result" line to my function. Thus, every time it evaluates my function, it prints the value of the function. When I run a bad case, I get something like this:

```
>>> a,b,c=opt.fmin_l_bfgs_b(lambda pars: coalHMM.coalHMMgf(chmm,pars[0],.6,pars[1],.000001,.000001,50000,10000,pars[2],10000,5,10,0,p=1),[.1,.2,10000],bounds=[(.000001,.999999),(.000001,.599999),(4000,100000)],approx_grad=1,iprint=5,epsilon=1e-5,factr=1e5)
RUNNING THE L-BFGS-B CODE

           * * *

Machine precision = 2.220D-16
 N =            3     M =           10

At X0         0 variables are exactly at the bounds
216599.857913
216599.857913
216599.787373
216606.008249
216599.857968

At iterate    0    f=  2.16600D+05    |proj g|=  5.51559D+00
92823.559439
92823.559439
92823.5563853
92829.0821432
92823.559463
92823.5584543
92823.5584543
92823.5554005
92829.0811585
92823.5584784
92823.5545111
92823.5545111
92823.5514573
92829.0772149
92823.554535
92823.5387401
92823.5387401
92823.5356864
92829.061443
92823.5387644
92823.475657
92823.475657
92823.4726033
92828.9983542
92823.475681
92823.2233259
92823.2233259
92823.2202723
92828.7460035
92823.2233502
92822.2139978
92822.2139978
92822.2109435
92827.7365952
92822.2140218
92818.1766824
92818.1766824
92818.1736284
92823.6989603
92818.1767058
92802.0273601
92802.0273601
92802.0243085
92807.5483614
```

As you can see, it just keeps evaluating, and evaluating, and evaluating... the problem is that each evaluation takes about a minute, so this is the result of quite a long wait...

My hunch is that it's a problem with the line search, but I don't know enough of the details to really work out what's going on...

Comment: Wow, this line IS long. You know, usually you should not make lines much longer than 80 characters...

Comment: You should really provide a minimal, *reproducible* piece of example code that showcases the issue.

Comment: Iirc BFGS doesn't have to converge to a solution in all cases, so maybe that's your problem? Just a guess.